# when to use younger than and younger to?

Tags: adjectives

Which one is correct?
She is younger than me.
Or
She is younger to me.

My teacher said, some adjectives like ' senior, junior, superior, inferior, major, minor, interior, posterior, younger, elder, prefer' are not followed by 'than' instead 'to'. 
So, are these adjectives correct to be used with 'to'?

Comment: In US usage, "older" and "younger" generally use "than", while most of the words in that list generally use "to".  (For "prefer" it would usually be "preferred over".)

Comment: 'Major to', for example, is not used in the sense 'X is considered major to Y'.

Comment: *Prefer* is not an adjective: You may be thinking of *preferable*, which opens up a whole new inquiry

Answer (score 3):

Simon is correct about "younger than"; this may be because "younger" is a comparative adjective, similar to his example of "hotter", and many others. In the case of "elder", it has largely been replaced in comparative adjectival use by "older", so we would say "older than him" rather than "elder than him".

Your teacher was partially correct about the other words. They are not comparative adjectives and are not followed by "than" unless in comparative constructions using "more", such as "He was more senior than Jane". Note that this means he was in a more senior role (but not necessarily responsible for Jane; he might even be in a different company) than Jane, whereas "he was senior to Jane" usually implies that he was in a more senior role but also was directly responsible for her.

I make no comment about "prefer", which is the only verb in your adjectival list.

Comment: Worth noting that all these adjectives that take _to_ **are** in fact comparatives—just not in English. They’re Latin comparatives: _junior_ ‘younger’, _senior_ ‘older’, _superior_ ‘upper/higher’, _inferior_ ‘lower’, _major_ ‘bigger’, _minor_ ‘smaller’, _interior_ ‘(more) inner’, _posterior_ ‘hinder’, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I've only heard people say "Jane is younger than Joan." Dictionaries describe "than" (as a conjunction) as a word used for comparisons. For example:
"Jane is taller than Joan."
"Jane is smarter than Joan."
and so on. (Lucky Jane!!)

I think your teacher slipped up, and it isn't clear to me what precise point they were trying to make.

Answer (score 1):

You either say "younger **than** or "junior **to**". I've occasionally seen the prepositions transposed, but I would consider such usage to be erroneous.